# jQuery $(document).on("click, ".class") vs jQuery $('#container').on("click, ".class")

Tags: jquery

```
$('#container').on("click", ".class", function(e) {
      some code
});
```

or

```
$(document).on("click", ".class", function(e) {
      some code
});
```

Can anyone advise which is faster? Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't matter actually! `#container` is just more specefic!

Comment: i think first one is better coz you dont need to bubble up too far compare to first one. but i dont know which is faster though

Comment: @Pekka That's what I thought but the flip side to the first is that jQuery must first find #container..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's generally better to bind the handler to the most specific element that contains all the dynamic elements you want to delegate to. When you use delegation, an internal jQuery handler runs any time the event occurs anywhere in the element that it's bound to (either `document` or `#container` in your examples), and then it tests whether the target matches the selector argument. So if you bind to a larger element, the handler runs more often, and this may impact responsiveness.

The performance of finding `#container` is negligible. This only happens once, when you first bind the handler. It's also very efficient, because browsers optimize ID and class lookups.

Comment: What is the performance hit these days with $(document).on("click", ".class", function(){/* actions */}); ? If it needs to be called because the class doesn't exist yet on the DOM when the page loads, is this still a no-no?

Comment: Even though the class doesn't exist yet, usually  a container will exist when the page loads. That's why I recommend using the container instead of `$(document)`.

Comment: In my case, I need to call it from inside a Bootstrap Popover - which doesn't really exist in a container (just above the </body tag); and the popover itself doesn't "exist" until clicked on either... or can you think of a better way of doing that?

Comment: In that case you use `$(document)` and live with the overhead.